# Definition of $p$-class of $p$-group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

I read this sentence somewhere:

> ... an epimorphism from the finitely presented group $A$ to the largest $p$-group of $p$-class $c$ which is a quotient of $A$ ...

May I clarify how is "largest $p$-group of $p$-class $c$ which is a quotient of $A$" defined?

Comment: Which part of the definition is the problem? Do you know what the $p$-class of a $p$-group is (I am not completely sure what they might mean by this actually)?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, I am not sure about all these definitions. What do you mean by the $p$-class of a $p$-group?

Comment: Could you provide the details of where this is from? My guess would be that by $p$-class they mean simply class (ie, nilpotency class), but they might mean something else.

Comment: It is possible that it means what is often called the exponent $p$-class, which is the minimal length of a central series in which all factors are elementary abelian. But I am only guessing! You can define the lower exponent $p$-central series in a similar way to the lower central series.

Comment: It is from Section 47.14-3 EpimorphismPGroup of a GAP manual at http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap47.html; I have modified some notation to make it look "nicer".

Comment: It is defined in 47.14-1 (and @DerekHolt guessed correctly)

Comment: Okay thanks a lot!!

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, by the way, how is $G^p$ defined? Is it the largest subgroup of $G$ in which all element to the power $p$ is trivial?

Comment: No, it is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing the $p$'th power of each element in $G$.

Comment: Note that then all elements of $G/G^p$ have order $p$.

Answer (score 3):

The $p$-class of a $p$-group $G$ is the length of its lower $p$-central series.

The $p$-central series of $G$ is defined by $U_1:=G$, $U_i:=[G,U_{i−1}]U^p_{i−1}$.

In GAP, these are given by `PClassPGroup` and `PCentralSeries` respectively. For some orders in the small groups library, `PClassPGroup` is one of the precomputed parameters to speed up selection (see `?AllSmallGroups`).

Note that the $p$-class of a $p$ group and the nilpotency class of the group are different notions. E.g, if a $p$-group has the $p$-class 2, then it's only true that its nilpotency class is not greater than two. For example, these abelian groups of order 64 have $p$-class 2:

```
gap> l:=AllSmallGroups(Size,64,IsAbelian,true,PClassPGroup,2);;
gap> List(l,StructureDescription);
[ "C4 x C4 x C4", "C4 x C4 x C2 x C2", "C4 x C2 x C2 x C2 x C2" ]
```